# ABPeoplePickerNavigationController transparent top bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, transparency, transparent

I use standard ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and when I had dragged table with contacts I saw that top bar is transparent. I can't solve it. It looks awful.

I tried to set [UIColor whiteColor] to everything I can reach: navigationBar, all subviews of ABPeoplePickerNavigationController and all subviews of it's topViewController. I tried to set different bar styles to navigation bar. Nothing help.

[image: Transperent top]

Here is code

```
@interface MNFindClientVC () <ABPeoplePickerNavigationControllerDelegate>
@property (nonatomic, strong) ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *addressBookController;
-(void)openPhoneBook;
@end

@implementation MNFindClientVC
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
        [super viewDidLoad];
        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"phonebook"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(openPhoneBook)];
        self.addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
        self.addressBookController.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
}

-(void)openPhoneBook
{
    [self presentViewController:self.addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

Sorry for my english. Thank you:)

Comment: Sorry, it is still working for me, you can comment out the rightBarButtonItem line and test again.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when using a UINavigationBar that was translucent. You can solve this problem by disabling translucency of the UINavigationBar when in a ABPeoplePickerNavigationContrller with the following code (Tested in iOS 8):

```
_addressBookController = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
[_addressBookController setPeoplePickerDelegate:self];

[[UINavigationBar appearanceWhenContainedIn:[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController class], nil] setTranslucent:NO];

[self presentViewController:_addressBookController animated:YES completion:nil];
```